# Firmas de una app con archivo .pepk

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-play, keystore

Tengo una duda, creé tres aplicaciones y quiero actualizarlas, guardo todos los archivos en carpetas con las firmas generadas, pero dos de ellas **no he podido actualizarlas porque no encuentro ningún archivo .jks pero tienen en cambio un archivo .pepk**, pero al cargarla me aparecen los siguientes errores, que estoy haciendo mal ?

Los textos son los siguientes:

Gracias!

> Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> Failed to read key iordee from store "C:\Users\iorde\Desktop\APPS ANDROID STUDIO\APP Peine\private_key.pepk": DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=107, too big.
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

[image: fallo 1]

> DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=107, too big.
> [image: fallo 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas actualizar tus aplicaciones es demasiado importante usar el mismo certificado con el cual subiste la aplicación originalmente, por esto es importante respaldar en lugar seguro.

**Para firmar las aplicaciones deberías tener los archivos `.jks` o `.keystore`, si únicamente tienes el archivo `private_key.pepk` este no se usa para firmar**, es  clave privada cifrada con una clave que solo Google puede descifrar y que debiste usar para para transferir la clave a Google cuando te inscribes en Play App Signing, lo cual se debió realizar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debes ir a [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console/), `Setup` > `App Integrity` > dar clic en `Request key upgrade`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí puedes indicar que perdiste tu llave para firmar y te será proporcionada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]